# Движение противника в игровом цикле

Tags: c++, разработка-игр, sfml

Пишу простенькую игру на `sfml`. Не буду вдаваться в подробности - опишу кратко, как все реализовано.

У меня есть игровой цикл, в котором отслеживаются `event'ы` и рисуется графика игры (по примеру туториалов). На данный момент в игре есть мой персонаж - он может двигаться и стрелять.
Схематически, игровой цикл выглядит так:

```
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(600, 800), "Test");

sf::Event _event;
while (window.isOpen()) // Игровой цикл.
{
    while(window.pollEvent(_event)  // Цикл event'ов.
    {
        ...
    }

    // Рисуем графику.
    ...
}
```

Теперь я хочу добавить противника - он появляется вверху карты и идет вниз (не постоянно - иногда встанет постоит немного и пойдет дальше, т.е., по задумке он не предсказуемый).
Но тут возникла проблема. Я хотел, чтобы в цикле с вероятностью `50%` противник спускался вниз. Вроде-как все OK:

```
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(600, 800), "Test");

sf::Event _event;
while (window.isOpen()) // Игровой цикл.
{
    while(window.pollEvent(_event)  // Цикл event'ов.
    {
        ...
    }

    if(rand()%2) // Вероятность 50%.
    {
        // Двигаем вниз нашего противника.
    }

    // Рисуем графику.
    ...
}
```

Но нет. Противник молниеносно пробегает по карте вниз и исчезает. Понимаю почему так происходит - цикл отрабатывает много раз за секунду и противник движется вниз.

**Итак, что же я хочу?** Я хочу чтобы противник плавно шел вниз, иногда замирая на месте.
Пожалуйста, подскажите как мне это сделать - опишите идею, а с реализацией справлюсь сам.

Comment: Сколько у вас кадров в секунду. Неужели вы считаете что за две доли секунды (т.е. 50%)  результат должен быть более заметен чем за долю секунды (т.е. 100%)? Так "влоб" не получится. Вам нужно отработать плавное движение с привязкой например к таймеру в 1/2 или 1/8 секунды (зависит от желаемой плавности), А потом... если вы хотите что б пошел, потом остановился... то сделать рандомный интервал например что б был от 1 до 5 секунд, через который поменяется состояние плыть или стоять.

Comment: Вам нужно ввести зависимости движения противника от deltaTime.

Comment: Обновляйте фиксированное количество раз в секунду, а не на каждой итерации цикла `while (window.isOpen())`

Comment: @nick_n_a, т.е., Вы предлагаете двигать игрока через определенное количество времени (каждые 1/8 секунды) ?

Comment: @VTT, что Вы имеете ввиду под "обновлять"? Двигать противника или рисовать графику? Спасибо

Comment: Я не знаю какое у вас игровое поле. Если у вас передвижение по одному пикселю - то лучше 1/8 сек - тогда будет довольно плавно. 1/2 сек - юзвери могут сказать что как-то рывками. Если у вас поле как у старых аркад, то может и раз в секунду.

Comment: @nick_n_a, прошу прощение за глупые вопросы - в sfml новичек :) Я так понял, что мне нужно двигать моего персонажа не каждую итерацию цикла, а сделать счетчик и внутри этого цикла каждые n секунд (например, 1/8 секунды) двигать моего персонажа вниз. Верно? Большое Вам спасибо!

Comment: @nick_n_a, получилось! Большое спасибо!!!